# bash script to loop through the folders and files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have folders naming ouput00035023031 to output000035023035. I have written the bash script to iterate through each folder and enter the folder. After entering the folder I want to run a program 'barycorr'. Which asks for three inputs. The inputs are filenames `*cl.evt`. The code is blelow :

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 5); do
    cd output0003502303$i
    echo -e "sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl.evt 
    sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt 
    sw00092413002sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169
    cd ..
done
```

I need to give first input the filenames `sw*pcw3po_cl.evt`, secondly the filename I want to save like `sw*xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt` and third the path where `sw*sao.fits.gz` file is located. The `*` changes according to which folder I am in. How to write the script now to run this program inside the each folder.

Comment: Will there always be exactly one match to each of those patterns in each folder? That is, is it possible a folder might have `sw1pcw3po_cl.evt` and also `sw2pcw3po_cl.evt`?

Comment: Yes, the `sw00035023032xpcw3po_cl.evt`  changes according to output folder number like output00035023032 and aloing with this there might be file name `sw00035023032xwtw2po_cl.evt` i.e pcw3 may changed to 'wtw2'.

Comment: Is the first part always the same as the folder name? That is, are the files `<foldername>xpcw3po_cl.evt`, `<foldername>xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt`, and `<foldername>sao.fits.gz`? Also, is it really necessary to `cd` into the folders, or would it work to pass paths (e.g. `<foldername>/<foldername>xpcw3po_cl.evt`) to the `barycorr` command? (The reason for the second question is that `cd` in scripts tends to be confusing, and can cause chain-reaction failures, so I prefer to avoid them.)

Comment: Yes, we can give path . We can make  list of  this command by changing the numerical value only like `00035023030' to '00035023035'. : ` echo -e "/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/00035023030/auxil/sw00035023030sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 ` . but if one number is missed like say ..31 then it program throws error. I need to bypass the error too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you should be able to do something like this:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 5); do
    printf '%s\n' "output0003502303${i}/sw00092413${i}"{xpcw3po_cl.evt,xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt,sao.fits.gz} |
        barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169
done
```

Explanation: the `printf '%s\n'` will print each of the following arguments (the `%s` part) followed by newlines (the `\n`) -- that is, each on a separate line. `printf` is much more controllable for things like this than `echo`.

As for those arguments, each one consists of the folder name and filename prefixes, and then the `{xpcw3po_cl.evt,xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt,sao.fits.gz}` part expands to each of those suffixes. Essentially, it's a shorthand for:

```
"output0003502303${i}/sw00092413${i}"xpcw3po_cl.evt
"output0003502303${i}/sw00092413${i}"xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt
"output0003502303${i}/sw00092413${i}"sao.fits.gz
```

Is this what's needed? If not, please clarify.